# Interface type check with Typescript for ReactElement

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-typescript

I have the following Form component set up. I want it to only accept two types of children:

1. A custom Input component, called `InputComponent`
2. A normal HTML `button` element

I would like to generate the following output:
`{myInput1: "abc", myInput2: "def"}`

**Form.tsx**

```
interface FormProps {
  children: Array<React.ReactElement<HTMLInputElement | HTMLButtonElement>>;
}

function Form({ children }: FormProps) {
  const handleSubmit = (event: React.SyntheticEvent) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    Children.map(children, (child) => {
      // ...
      // generate desired output here
      // ...
    });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <InputComponent name="myInput1" value="abc"/>
        <InputComponent name="myInput2" value="def"/>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </>
  );
}
```

I attempted to check if a given child matches the interface of an HTMLInputElement or HTMLButtonELement, and extracting its name and value only if it is an HTMLInputElement. I am struggling to be able to make this differentiation and would appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: Shouldn't the props type definition contain your custom `InputComponent` rather than `HTMLInputElement`?

Comment: @DBS is correct but if you really want to "typecheck" some data use typeguards